# Multiple elements click event in javascript - like jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, selector

I have a function that is working and looks like this:

```
var $$ = function(selector, context) {
    context = context || document;
    var elements = context.querySelectorAll(selector);
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(elements);
}

// My function
var myFunction = function() {
    $$( '.my-selector' ).forEach( function( element ) {
        element.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            console.log('Do something');
        });
    });
}
```

I would prefer it looks more like jQuery:

```
// My function
var myFunction = function() {
    $('.my-selector').click(function(e) {
        console.log('Do something');
    });
}
```

I can't figure out how to do that. Any ideas?

(I want my code to be independent of frameworks so I don't want jQuery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution1: with your own wrapper**: Fiddler [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nirus/hhtpn5fu/)

```
var $$ = function(selector, context) {
    context = context || document;
    var elements = context.querySelectorAll(selector);    
    var wrapper = function(elem){
      var element = elem;
      this.click = function(cb){
      element.forEach(function(el){
          el.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            cb.apply(element,[e]);
          });
      });   
      };
    };

    return new wrapper(Array.prototype.slice.call(elements));
}


$$("#test").click(function(e){
 console.log("Do something:"+e.type);
});
```

**Solution 2 directly binding to native element:** Fiddler [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nirus/2bt8jcb0/)

```
var $$ = function(selector, context) {
    context = context || document;
    var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(context.querySelectorAll(selector));    
     elements.click = function(cb){
        elements.forEach(function(el){
            el.addEventListener('click', function(e){
              cb.apply(elements,[e]);
            });
        });     
      };

    return elements;   
}

$$("#test").click(function(e){
 console.log("Do something:"+e.type);
});
```

Comment: Which of the solutions would you have used? The last one seems shorter so I would probably use that one.

Comment: 2nd solution is same as jquery coz you can access the element. In 1st solution you cant access the element but bind to the nested functions. I would go for 2nd one if i want it to be more like jquery.

Comment: @Jens did it helped you?

Comment: Then I will try out the second one soon and accept your solution if it works like expected. Thank you so much so far!